# How to split string at fixed numbers of character in clojure?

Tags: string, clojure, split

I'm new in ***clojure***. I'm learning about splitting string in various ways. I'm taking help from here:
https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.string/split
There is no example to split string at fixed number of character.

Let a string **"hello everyone welcome to here"**. I want to split this string after every ***4th*** char, so the output *(after split)* should be **["hell" "o ev" "eryo" "ne w" "elco" "me t" "o he" "re"]**. Note that *white space* is consider a char.

can anyone tell me, how can I do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

you could use `re-seq`:

```
user> (def s "hello everyone welcome to here")
#'user/s

user> (re-seq #".{1,4}" s)
("hell" "o ev" "eryo" "ne w" "elco" "me t" "o he" "re")
```

or partition the string, treating it as a seq:

```
user> (map (partial apply str) (partition-all 4 s))
("hell" "o ev" "eryo" "ne w" "elco" "me t" "o he" "re")
```

Comment: Thanks. It's awesome. It solve my problem. @leetwinski

Comment: It would be cleaner to `(require '[clojure.string :as str])` and use [`str/join`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.string/join) instead of `(partial apply str)`.

Comment: probably. Still `re-seq` approach is much faster (well, if you realize the seq)

Answer (score 5):

With transducers:

```
(def sample "hello everyone welcome to here")

(into [] (comp (partition-all 4) (map #(apply str %))) sample)
```

Slower than the other examples though :).

Comment: `(eduction (partition-all 4) (map #(apply str %)) sample)` to be pretentious :)

Answer (score 4):

```
(->> "hello everyone welcome to here"
     (partition-all 4)
     (map (partial apply str)))
```

Comment: Thanks. I got my answer.